# Перехват вывода консоли удаленного хоста golang

Tags: bash, golang

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как читать вывод выполнения bash скрипта построчно(в режиме реального времени) удаленного хоста и "выплевывать" в свою консоль(файл) каждую строку, ну или же через 2-3 секунды?

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "os"
    "log"

    "github.com/helloyi/go-sshclient"
)
func SshClientRunCommands(script string) {
    f2, err := os.OpenFile("1.log", os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    client, err := sshclient.DialWithKey("удаленный хост", "root", "путь к ключу")
    if err != nil {
        handleError(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
    client.Script(script).Run()
    
    out, _ := client.Script(script).Output()
    
    defer f2.Close()
    logger:= log.New(f2, "", log.LstdFlags)
    logger.Println(out)
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `client.Script(script).SetStdio(f2, f2).Run()`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не используйте `panic(err)` как в этом ответе в своем приложении.
я немного зарефакторил ваш метод. в вашем примере вы 2 раза запускаете скрипт.

```
func main() {
    SshClientRunCommands("ls -al / && sleep 5 && ls -al /home")
}

func SshClientRunCommands(script string) {
    f2, err := os.OpenFile("1.log", os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f2.Close()


    client, err := sshclient.DialWithKey("удаленный хост", "root", "путь к ключу")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // можно заменить на handleError(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
    
    remoteScript := client.Script(script) // создаем сущность sshclient.RemoteScript, которая отвечает за удаленный запуск
    remoteScript.SetStdio(os.Stdout, os.Stderr) // указываем output скрипта. тут будет писать каждый раз, когда скрипт напечатает что-либо

    err = remoteScript.Run() // запуск скрипта
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

в моем ответе выхлоп печатается в Stdout, так как так нагляднее, но если вам надо писать в файл, то можете заменить на `remoteScript.SetStdio(f2, f2)`